# Next button div close focus input select

Tags: jquery, html, css, popup

Hi I have popup div with a next button inside. after clicking the next button the div will fadeout and focus on select input.

If you click one of these categories it will have a popup
[image: If you click one of these categories it will have a popup]

This is the popup with next button
[image: This is the popup with next button]

After clicking the next button the popup will close and focus on this select option
[image: After clicking the next button the popup will close and focus on this select option]

code for my next button

```
    <div class="col-lg-12">

      <section id="btn-click" class="pull-right">

        <p>

          <button id="btn_cat" class="btn btn-blue">Next</button>

        </p>

      </section>

   </div>
```

Comment: So.. what's the question?

Comment: So what's the problem? Where's the code?

Comment: Jquery for the next button to make the div fadeout and focus on the select option input

Comment: You should at least try, we are not here to make your code. We help. At least provide a fiddle with what you already tried or isn't working.

Comment: I do have a code but I don't know how will I create it on jsfiddle

Comment: You want something like this: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/ ?

Comment: you need to manually focus on the textfield after the popup is closed. USing jquery it is possible.